# How to set ViewModel's property from View without explicit type conversion

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-7.1, mvvm-light

I'm newbie in mvvm so I really need your help.

In my wp7 application I'm trying to use MVVM Light toolkit.
I have two views: "Main" and 2-mode "New", which is intended for addiing some item and editing some item.

```
class Item
{
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

When I'm navigating to NewView from MainView I add "Name" parameter in query string, if i want to edit item. 
On NewView I have textbox:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Name="txtListName" Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
```

NewViewModel:

```
class NewViewModel
{
  public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
```

How can I set ItemName property from NewView **without** code in *NewView.xaml.cs* like this

```
(this.DataContext as NewViewModel).ItemName = name;
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: If the ViewModel has a value, all you need to add is a two way binding between View and ViewModel and the setting of the DataContext.

Comment: I'm creating NewViewModel using ViewModelLocator <pre>DataContext="{Binding New, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"<code>. I'm parsing query string on NewView, so how can I initialize NewViewModel fields from NewView without explicit type conversion? I've tryed to set textbox (with two way binding) from NewView Text property with value from query string, but my NewViewModel property has not be setted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided this problem. On NewView I set to textbox two-way binding:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Name="txtListName" Text="{Binding ItemName,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

and then in view's loaded event I set text's property of this textbox:

```
void NewView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String name;
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("Name", out name))
        this.txtListName.Text = name;
}
```

After that property ItemName of NewViewModel is setted!